# loop through names array letter by letter

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

```
let names = ['pete', 'dave', 'sara', 'toni', 'michael'];
let name = "";
let names2 = [];


// names[i][j]



console.log (names);
console.log (names2);
```

I have to find a way to loop through the names array letter by letter and have the output of names2 to be that same array buy processed letter by letter.

So far i have this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
for (let j = 0; j < names[i].length; j++) {
    name += names[i][j];
    names2 += name;
    name = "";

console.log (names);
console.log (names2);
```

The output should be:

```
['pete', 'dave', 'sara', 'toni', 'michael']
['pete', 'dave', 'sara', 'toni', 'michael']
```

(this second one written down letter by letter and the first one is just the normal array that we set at the begining)

But what I'm getting is:

```
['pete', 'dave', 'sara', 'toni', 'michael']
petedavesaratonimichael
```

Can anyone help me?

```js
let names = ['pete', 'dave', 'sara', 'toni', 'michael'];
let name = "";
let names2 = [];

for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < names[i].length; j++) {
      name += names[i][j];
      names2 += name;
      name = "";
  }
}

console.log (names);
console.log (names2);
```

Comment: You don't need a for loop for that

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please edit the title to something descriptive of your question. Like "loop through names array letter by letter"

Comment: @vacadery Keep in mind, that you can a code snippet to a question to help illustrate your problem. I just added one for you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure what this excercise is about, but here's a solution (without loops but with `Array.map` and `Array.reduce`).

```js
let names = ['pete', 'dave', 'sara', 'toni', 'michael'];

const convert = (names) => names.map(name => Array.from(name).reduce((result, c) => `${result}${c}`, ''))

console.log(names);
console.log(convert(names));
```

In your solution, you are probably coercing your array to a string by using the  overloaded `+=` operator. You should be using `Array.push` or `Array.concat` instead when adding elements.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `names2 += name;` you are not adding `name` value to the array `names2`, instead it's converting the value to string and then concatenating.

To add to the array you should use the method `push`:

```
names2.push(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let names = ['pete', 'dave', 'sara', 'toni', 'michael'];

const convertedNames= names.slice();

console.log(names);
console.log(convertedNames);
```